# How to attach a TTL to every entry in Redis Cache in Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, spring-cache, redisson

Say I have a model `Employee` which has an expiry component to it. When the first request comes to retrieve the employee details, I want to store it in cache with a TTL based on the **expiry** of the `Employee` object (`employee.getExpiry()`).

I am unable to do it using `@Cachable` in Spring. I looked at suggestion given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054774/how-to-configure-different-ttl-for-each-redis-cache-when-using-cacheable-in-spr), but this makes use of `cacheManager` and there's no way for me to dynamically set the TTL or expiry on that particular cache object.

I am using Redission for caching and I tried the following:

```
@Cacheable(value = "employees", key = "#designation")
public Employee retrieve(String designation) {
        LOG.info("Retrieving Employee with query parameters: {}", designation);
        Employee employee = employeeRepository.findByDesignation(designation);
        LOG.info("Retrieved Employee: {}", employee);
        RMapCache<String, Employee> employeCache = redissonClient.getMapCache("employees");
        employeCache.put(employee.getDesignation(), employee, employee.getExpiry(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return employee;
    }
```

But it doesn't work. I am manually setting the TTL using `redissionClient`, but that particular entry gets replaced by `@Cacheable(value = "employees", key = "#designation")`

When I try without the `@Cacheable`, it seems to work.

So my question is, how can I set TTL dynamically using `@Cacheable`? If not, is manually doing it using `RedissonClient` the only way?

Answer (score 0):

Spring CacheManager API doesn't allow to define different TTL per entry. `RMapCache` object is the only way in this case.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please tell me if there is any difference in performance of the application in terms of CRUD operations using `RMapCache` instead of `@Cacheable`? I am not sure how `@Cacheable` works under the hood

Comment: It's subject of benchmark of particular use case. You could consider to use RBucket object and `RBucket.expire()` method if you use TTL parameter only.